# android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable error

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I'm getting this error when trying to implement Adaptive Icons while my app crashes on startup.

I can't imagine why I'm getting this error because in the files mentioned in the error log below (`MainActivity` and `BaseActivity`), I don't use both `AdaptiveIconDrawable` and `BitmapDrawable`.

```
2018-04-28 16:50:17.014 31282-31282/de.markustippner.wondermusic2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.markustippner.wondermusic2, PID: 31282
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.markustippner.wondermusic2/de.markustippner.wondermusic2.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
        at com.afollestad.appthemeengine.ATE.applyTaskDescription(ATE.java:259)
        at com.afollestad.appthemeengine.ATE.preApply(ATE.java:128)
        at com.afollestad.appthemeengine.ATEActivity.onCreate(ATEActivity.java:22)
        at de.markustippner.wondermusic2.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:44)
        at de.markustippner.wondermusic2.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:137)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7117)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7108)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
```

The "funny" part with this error message is that when I remove "mipmap-anydpi-v26" folder, my app doesn't crash anymore but then Adaptive Icons are not working too...

The lines where the error is thrown are in both cases:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: How about removing the swearing?

Comment: @alexanders916 Thanks but this does'nt help...

Comment: With the stack trace alone, we can't solve the problem... how about posting the line of code where the exception is thrown?

Comment: @alexanders916 OK, edited my question above...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you're using [App Theme Engine](https://github.com/garretyoder/app-theme-engine), which tries to use you app icon as a bitmap. But since Android 8.0 you can set an adaptive icon, which is not a bitmap, thus the App Theme Engine crashes on it.

This issue has been [reported here](https://github.com/garretyoder/app-theme-engine/issues/8), but it's not been fixed yet (and probably won't, since it hasn't seen any updates for two years).

You might be able so fix this yourself by forking the project and changing the [problematic part](https://github.com/garretyoder/app-theme-engine/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/afollestad/appthemeengine/ATE.java#L249) to not require a bitmap icon. Or alternatively, use another theme engine.

Comment: Thank you. Forking the project and changing it to my needs has fixed the problem!

Comment: I have same issue occurred and still not solved.
android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
What can I do?

Comment: Any idea on adaptive icon??

Answer (score 22):

In ATE.java file, implement this

```
@NonNull
static private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(@NonNull Drawable drawable) {
    final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bmp;
}
```

And change

```
if (icon == null)
        icon = ((BitmapDrawable) activity.getApplicationInfo().loadIcon(activity.getPackageManager())).getBitmap();
```

to

```
if (icon == null)
        icon = getBitmapFromDrawable(activity.getApplicationInfo().loadIcon(activity.getPackageManager()));
```

Comment: @MayankSharma Yes, it did.

Answer (score 4):

I am also facing same error. It's due to `ic_launcher` creating automatically `AdaptiveIcon`. I just remove adaptive `icon(ic_launcher.xml)` and run, so it's working.

Comment: also remove **ic_launcher_round.xml** if any