# Android studio debugger | android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Tags: android-graphics

I am trying to run this app on my android 11 device
https://github.com/AshiVered/monolaunch.
But, I am giving this error
`2024-01-16 18:27:00.487  5207-5207  AndroidRuntime          com.monobogdan.monolaunch            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.monobogdan.monolaunch, PID: 5207 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.monobogdan.monolaunch/com.monobogdan.monolaunch.Launcher}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3648) at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2116) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7723) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:999) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable at com.monobogdan.monolaunch.AppListView.rebuildUI(AppList.java:159) at com.monobogdan.monolaunch.AppListView.<init>(AppList.java:120) at com.monobogdan.monolaunch.Launcher.onCreate(Launcher.java:249) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3648)  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2116)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7723)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:999`

thanks

I searched on Google and came across this topic:
[android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077917/android-graphics-drawable-adaptiveicondrawable-cannot-be-cast-to-android-graphic)
It does seem related, because the app crashes precisely on the subject of app icons,
But there it is about changing something in the icon of the application; Here, if I understand correctly, the problem is with the icons of the entire device